# JQuery UI popup elements not positioning correctly

Tags: jquery, positioning, jquery-ui-dialog, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am using both JQuery UI Dialog and JQuery UI autocomplete both have the same erroneous behavior when they popup, the position is always 0,0! I have tried some different position arguments when popping up the dialog but non seems to help.

Any clues? Is this a bug in the position calculation in JQuery? Or is this some css bug?

Versions are 1.4.2 and 1.8.0

Comment: For the autocomplete my code looks exactly like the example at http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote (of course i have another selector and service url). I will try to isolate to a little nice example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I found out that this error was caused by a external jquery script plugin called jquery.dimensions... - "As of jQuery 1.2.6, the dimensions plugin has been merged into core." So I just removed the plugin and now everything is working as expected.

Comment: If there was a programmers fantasy league I'd draft you #1 overall. I nearly shattered my PC's screen trying to track this down.

Comment: Seriously I just spent a couple of hours trying to figure out why the $%@^#%^@#% autocomplete results were showing up at the top of my page. Thank you!!!!!!

Comment: I removed the jquery.dimensions.js but still on IE7, the results `<ul>`is not on placed below my parent div. Can you take a look at my implementation, here it is,

`appendTo: "#results",
    open: function(){
     var position = $("#results").position(),
         left = position.left, top = position.top;
     
       $("#results > ul").css({left: (left + 15) + "px",
                 top: (top + 30) + "px", width: (206) + "px", float: "left"});
    }`

Answer (score 1):

If Okku's answer doesn't fix things, you may find you've forgotten the file `jquery.position.js` from your includes.